# show content based on logged in user=role in wordpress with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this working ok:

```
<?php global $user_login; get_currentuserinfo();
if ($user_login) :?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=download_report&download_report">Download Inventory of Mobile Apps</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I am seeking to alter it to display **this specific content based on logged in user ROLE.** So basically something like if role is=administrator show, if not hide for all other logged in users.

|||| How can I alter my current code to write an if statement that checks for logged in user role then if specific role like admin, show content; and if not hide?

Fail Log:
*Recent:*

```
<?php global $user_login; get_currentuserinfo();
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            if( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) { :?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=download_report&download_report">Download Inventory of Mobile Apps</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

*Most Recent:*

```
<?php 
global $user_login, $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
if (in_array('administrator', $user_info->roles)) {

<li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=download_report&download_report">Download Inventory of Mobile Apps</a></li>
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
<?php
global $user_login, $current_user;

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

    if (in_array('administrator', $user_info->roles)) {
        // content
    }
}
?>
```

**Combined with your *most recent* code:**

```
<?php 
global $user_login, $current_user; 

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
    if (in_array('administrator', $user_info->roles)) { 
?>    
<li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=download_report&download_report">Download Inventory of Mobile Apps</a></li>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Updated code sample, though if you're logged in and it's still "breaking the site", please provide the actual error(s).

Comment: So it isn't breaking the site anymore; but it won't work with user role 'Site Manager'.

Comment: Hi @stealthyninja, this worked for me so thanks very much!  Just wondering though how I would add multiple user roles?  So, if I want the 'administrator' and the 'editor' user roles to have access for example?

Comment: @damienoneill2001 - Please ask this as another question.

Comment: @stealthyninja no worries, new question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060128/show-content-based-on-multiple-user-roles-in-wordpress