# Show content based on multiple user roles in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to display content based on multiple different user roles.

The aim is to display content for two or three different user roles, and then block it for other user roles, displaying a message that it is only for certain logged in users.

So far, I have the following:

```
<?php 
    global $user_login, $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
    $roles = array (
        'administrator',
        'subscriber',
    );

if (is_user_logged_in() && in_array( $roles, $user_info->roles)) {

//content here

} else {

// they aren't logged in, so show them the login form

}
?>
```

At the moment, the issue I am having seems to be that the code is looking for both the administrator and subscriber roles at the same time and as a result, the if statement is not satisfied and the login form shows.

If I change $roles to 'administrator' or 'subscriber', it then works fine.

So, how  would I search through the array to display either role, not all of them.

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556925/show-content-based-on-logged-in-user-role-in-wordpress-with-php

Comment: Hi @rahul-s, thanks for the response but I am not sure you fully read what I am looking for.  That is the code I am using, but I need it for multiple user roles, not just one.  That post is just for the administrator.  Thanks though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:
**[array_intersect (link)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)**

array_intersect will check between two array to see if the needle (`$roles`) exists in the haystack (`$user_info->roles`). I have tested this against my own and works well.

See below the use of `array_intersect`.

```
<?php 
    global $user_login, $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
    $roles = array (
        'administrator',
        'subscriber',
    );

if (is_user_logged_in() && array_intersect( $roles, $user_info->roles)) {

echo 'success';

} else {

echo 'failure';

}
?>
```

**Example 1: [LINK](https://3v4l.org/V4Hf2)** the `$roles` array does not match.

**Example 2: [LINK](https://3v4l.org/Tigdm)** the `$roles` array has one match.

Comment: Hi @jamie-sterling, spot on, exactly what I needed.  That is working now for me too, thanks for the help!

Comment: @damienoneill2001, Happy to help!